# How to create a x-y scatterplot from attributes in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, statistics, graph, scatterplot

There are a few old packages that allow the creation of x-y scatter plots from attributes in vector data

(Scattergram for 1.7) http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/scattergrammidentify/

(SPQR for very early editions) http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Software/Spqr/

But does anyone know of a package for 2.0 that would do this?  or a way to rig up the old ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already many plugins which use the Python module [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

[image]

(Midvatten here)

If you know Python, it is not very difficult to use the Python console or a Python script in the Processing Toolbox.

[image]

In the same way, you can use a [R](http://www.r-project.org/) script in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: could you provide any sample R scripts for the processing toolbox that do something similar?  I'm not familiar enough to build something from scratch but could probably improvise given some building blocks.

Comment: Examine the provided examples.

Comment: hmm. I seem to be running into this bug for R output:  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9203  although its happening on a 32bit installation of qgis.   The outputs are all empty or are text pointing to a *.html.png file

Comment: sorry, I do not use Windows (and no problem for me)