# Plotting "diagram" in matplotlib?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, diagram

I want to plot a diagram like this:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

Unfortunately, I have no idea what these diagrams are called and therefore I do not know where to search for an explanation of how they are created.

Does anyone know how they are called and whether they can be created in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of diagrams are called "scatter plots" (streudiagramm). If you have installed **numpy** and **maplotlib python libraries** in your system, you can copy/paste the "simple demo of a scatter plot" in the Python Console and this is the result:

[image]

Of course, you can also run the code as script. After, you can modify controllably the code for telling you how it works.

Comment: Shoot. I copied the wrong link! My fault. I meant this one http://geography.oii.ox.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/download-9.png

Comment: @Stophface It is convenient to do another question with the correct link.

Comment: I did that already http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140327/how-is-this-diagram-called

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of matplotlib with PyQGIS in in GIS SE, look at [How to create a x-y scatterplot from attributes in QGIS 2.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90382/how-to-create-a-x-y-scatterplot-from-attributes-in-qgis-2-0/90392#90392), for example (3D scatter plot).

If you know matplotlib, it is not very difficult to use it in the Python console, as [xulnic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/45066/xunilk) says, or in a processing script. There also many plugins which use it as the, [Contour plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) , or the [midvatten plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/midvatten/) for example

In addition to the answer of xulnic some other applications:

Rose diagram

[image]

Stereonet diagram (for geologist)

[image]